# MongoDB - how to check uniqueness of one property based on another

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to identify bad data in a mongo DB and struggling to get the aggregation right.  The documents look like this:

```
{
  clientCode: 'abc',
  categoryId: 123,
  externalCategoryId: 'foo',
  ...
}
```

externalCategoryId is client supplied, and should be unique for the clientCode, but could be duplicated for a different clientCode.

The bad data I'm trying to identify is if there is two different categoryId's with the same externalCategoryId for a given clientCode.

This doesn't need to be efficient or run in an application, it's just a one time query for now to check the sanity of the data.

I've tried following documentation, and other suggestions for aggregation/summation, but haven't been able to get it yet.  I've been going down the road of

```
{
  clientCode: 'abc',
  externalCategoryId: 'foo',
  numCategoryIds: 2
}
```

but I'm open to other suggestions as well.

I've been evolving the attempt, so I don't have previous attempts readily available.  This is the query in it's current form:

```
db.getCollection('funds').aggregate([
    { $group: {
        _id: { clientCode: '$clientCode', externalCategoryId: '$externalCategoryId', categoryId: '$categoryId' }
    }},
    { $group: {
        _id: { clientCode: '$_id.clientCode', externalCategoryId: '$_id.externalCategoryId' },
        categoryIds: { $sum: 1 }
    }}
])
```

Sample documents:

```
{ clientCode: "abc", categoryId: 1, externalCategoryId: "foo" }
{ clientCode: "xyz", categoryId: 2, externalCategoryId: "foo" }
{ clientCode: "abc", categoryId: 3, externalCategoryId: "bar" }
{ clientCode: "abc", categoryId: 4, externalCategoryId: "foo" }
```

Expected aggregation would be:

```
{ clientCode: "abc", externalCategoryId: "foo", numberCategoryIds: 2 }
{ clientCode: "abc", externalCategoryId: "bar", numberCategoryIds: 1 }
{ clientCode: "xyz", externalCategoryId: "foo", numberCategoryIds: 1 }
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show the aggregation queries you have tried?

Comment: Added the current work in progress query, I haven't been saving past iterations though.

Comment: Not so sure if I caught your question well, esp where you say _"externalCategoryId is client supplied, and should be unique for the clientCode, but could be duplicated for a different clientCode"_

Comment: But I believe you are heading in the right direction. What you may need to do is create a pipeline step to group the documents by the `clientCode` and `externalCategoryId` fields, then create an arry of `categoryId`s using `$push` as follows `db.getCollection('funds').aggregate([
    { $group: {
        _id: { clientCode: '$clientCode', externalCategoryId: '$externalCategoryId' }, categoryIds: { "$push": '$categoryId' }
    }} ])` then inspect this array, perhaps analyse its size etc.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit by perhaps throwing in a bunch of documents for testing and then show us the expected aggregation output from that sample?

Comment: Definitely, added to the original text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try running the following aggregation pipeline:

```
db.funds.aggregate([ 
    { 
        "$group": { 
            "_id": { 
                "clientCode": "$clientCode", 
                "externalCategoryId": "$externalCategoryId" 
            }, 
            "categoryIds": { "$push": "$categoryId" } 
        }
    },
   { 
        "$project": { 
            "_id": 0,
            "clientCode": "$_id.clientCode", 
            "externalCategoryId": "$_id.externalCategoryId",
            "numberCategoryIds": { "$size": "$categoryIds" } 
        }
    } 
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "clientCode" : "abc",
    "externalCategoryId" : "foo",
    "numberCategoryIds" : 2
}

/* 2 */
{
    "clientCode" : "xyz",
    "externalCategoryId" : "foo",
    "numberCategoryIds" : 1
}

/* 3 */
{
    "clientCode" : "abc",
    "externalCategoryId" : "bar",
    "numberCategoryIds" : 1
}
```